# Two relationships in Views

Tags: views

I'm wondering if the following construction is posible with Views in Drupal in combination with relationships. I build this in Drupal:

```
Manager <--(Entity Reference)--> Group <--(Entity Reference)--> User
```

A manager can control groups with different users, so I have the following setup:

> Manager A <--> Group A <--> User 1
>  Manager A <--> Group A <-->
>   User 3
>  Manager A <--> Group A <--> User 5
>  Manager B <-->
>   Group B <--> User 2
>  Manager B <--> Group C <--> User 4
>   Manager B <--> Group C <--> User 6
>  Manager B <--> Group C <-->
>   User 7

I'm looking for a way to generate a view with the logged in manager to get all the users of the group the manager is part of.

So we get this result when I'm logged in with manager B:

> User 2
>  User 4
>  User 6
>  User 7

I tried to create an Contextual filters with an default value of the logged in user. Then 2 relations: one for the

```
Manager <--(Entity Reference)--> Group
```

ans an second one for the

```
Group <--(Entity Reference)--> User
```

And then I tried to make fields with an relationship. But only I get is no results. Is there a way to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You will want you view set up so that:

- The view is displaying Users.
- There is a relationship from User to Group
- There is a relationship from Group to Manager
- You add the contextual filter that defaults to the currently logged in user. Make this filter use the Group-Manager relationship.

Comment: You suggest to use _Relation_ instead of _Entity Reference_?

Comment: @Rommel in Views under Advanced, add relationships that rooby mentions. Keep an eye for Referec**ing** and Referenc**ed**, these are two different things. Try using Referenc**ed** for both. Else if that doesn't work, try Referec**ing** for both.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I tried it (and I keep an eye for **ed** and **ing**) but I keep getting no results...